# Audio Signal ground to earth ground?

Tags: noise, signal, ground, grounding, buzzing

I have a NAIM amp (some audio amp) working very well. Recently, added a ARCAM phono preamp (some pre-amp for turntable) to it. Once the phono preamp is connected to NAIM amp, there will be clear buzz noise, even not turning on the phono preamp.

It looks to be a ground loop issue. Bought two ground loop isolators, both just work little bit, still clear buzz noise. The NAIM amp is the only one with 3 pins plug power cable. The same phono preamp put on other amp with 2 pins plug power cable, there is no noise.

Two signal grounds on each device is connected, but still strong noise.

Some friend suggest this may not be a ground loop issue, instead missing signal ground to earth ground.

Get more confused. Will connecting signal ground to earth ground introduce a new ground loop? Also, is there any safety concern? (In the NAIM manual, it clearly state, the ground is not supposed to connect earth ground.)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please capitalise your post properly - including the title and all brand names. It makes a big difference to legibility, credibility and it is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: What is a "naim amp".  If you wrote that once, I'd assume a typo for "main amp", but you used "naim" twice, so maybe it was intentional?

Comment: just loop two ends of a wire around a grounded screw on each device, or use the FM ground, USB ground, etc. Once you connect the two device's ground, the buzz will go away. i used to keep an alligator clip biting a screw on my amp and the side of my laptop's USB socket; worked perfectly, but without it, BUZZZZZZZ!

Comment: @PeterBennett Naim is a high-fidelity audio manufacturer

Comment: That's why capitalisation makes it clear that it's a proper noun. It's Naim, not NAIM which would be appropriate for an initialisation (which it isn't). Arcam / ARCAM seem to use both forms on their website.

Comment: Did you connect the turntable to the phono preamp and connect the phono preamp to the power amp with good quality shielded audio cables? Cables from The Dollar Store and from Radio Shack are the same poor quality cables.

Comment: @Audioguru, Monster m1000 is that bad, right?

Comment: The Monster M-1000 stereo cables were discontinued maybe because their price was a ripoff and fake counterfeights are sold on ebay and Amazon.